# How to extract the token expiration time with the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package

Tags: c#, .net-core, adal

I want to use JSON web tokens for authentication in my .NET Core project. That's why I added the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package to it.

I'm familiar with the [JavaScript equivalent `jsonwebtoken` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) which provides a [`verify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) function to validate and decode the token.

Most of the time I only need to extract the payload to get the user and other information but there are some cases where I also need to know when the token expires (e.g. invalidating the token by storing it to the database and removing it after expiration).

I started with this sample code

```
public object ValidateAndDecodeToken(string token)
{
    SymmetricSecurityKey symmetricSecurityKey = GenerateSymmetricSecurityKey("db3OIsj+BXE9NZDy0t8W3TcNekrF+2d/1sFnWG4HnV8TZY30iTOdtVWJG8abWvB1GlOgJuQZdcF2Luqm/hccMw=="); // From config
        
    try
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            
        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey
        };
            
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        DateTime tokenExpiresAt = DateTime.Now; // TODO
        JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(encodedToken);
        Dictionary<string, string> tokenPayload = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.ToDictionary(claim => claim.Type, claim => claim.Value);

        return new { token, tokenExpiresAt, tokenPayload };
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private SymmetricSecurityKey GenerateSymmetricSecurityKey(string base64Secret)
{
    byte[] symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Secret);
    return new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey);
}
```

As you can see here I'm trying to extract the token expiration time and the payload. I think the payload should work fine but how can I extract the expiration information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your sample code, you should be able to get the expiry time as:

```cs
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

var tokenExpiresAt = validatedToken.ValidTo;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I almost got it, but what I'm missing is the token expiration time :) I updated my question to show the actual code and what I'm missing

Comment: Updated the answer based on the new sample :-)

Comment: For the use case you describe

"(e.g. invalidating the token by storing it to the database and removing it after expiration)."

you might be better off setting up the `tokenValidationParameters` appropriately (i.e. validate the expiry), and then removing invalid tokens, rather than using the expiry time directly.

Comment: thanks for your help! would you mind explaining your second comment a little bit more or provide a small code sample?

Comment: @ChrisM I would like to know that too :) Because I've seen that the code from the OP will throw an exception because the audience wasn't validated. But Im asking myself why should I validate that audience url or the token expiration?